# How to have addTA() not print legend when the indicator is overlaid on another chart?

Tags: r, quantmod

In this code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO")
candleChart(YHOO)
addTA(Cl(YHOO)/2, legend = "", on = NA )
```

the legend parameter of `addTa()` works as expected.

But the same value to that parameter does not work if I let `on = 1`:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("YHOO")
candleChart(YHOO)
addTA(Cl(YHOO)/2, legend = "", on = 1 )
```

It shows `Cl(YHOO)/2:` followed by the last adjusted price as the legend. How can I remove this legend? Also, is it possible to remove the last price of shown on the chart? I couldn't find any mention of this in the `chartSeries()` documentation.

The following is the output of my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-4   TTR_0.22-0       doParallel_1.0.8 iterators_1.0.7  xts_0.9-7       
[6] zoo_1.7-12       foreach_1.4.2    magrittr_1.5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6      lubridate_1.3.3  lattice_0.20-31  codetools_0.2-11 digest_0.6.8    
 [6] dplyr_0.4.2      assertthat_0.1   plyr_1.8.3       grid_3.2.1       R6_2.1.0        
[11] DBI_0.3.1        RSQLite_1.0.0    utilsSE_0.1      stringi_0.5-5    lazyeval_0.1.10 
[16] tools_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0    compiler_3.2.1   memoise_0.2.1
```

Comment: You might find this post helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090963/r-quantmod-chartseries-newta-chob-modify-legend-and-axis-primary-and-secundar