# When using package 'quantmod' in R, how to suppress the 'last price' line of text on a price chart?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am plotting a price chart using function `chartSeries()` in the R package `quantmod`.  Here's an example:

```
#Load package 'quantmod'
library(quantmod)

#Download quotes for VNQ
hist.xts <- getSymbols('VNQ',
                       from = '2006-1-1',
                       to = '2006-1-31',
                       auto.assign = F)

#Plot price chart
chartSeries(hist.xts, type = 'bars')
```

And here's the price chart:

[image: price chart]

How can I suppress the text "Last 64.050003" so that it doesn't appear on the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert the parameter `TA = NULL` as indincated in the documentation and in this example: http://www.quantmod.com/examples/charting/#chartseries

```
chartSeries(hist.xts, type = 'bars', TA = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks-- somehow I missed that in the documentation.  Do you know if there's a way to add a TA option like addVo() while still suppressing the "last price" text?

Comment: I've tried to access the parameter of the plot using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090963/r-quantmod-chartseries-newta-chob-modify-legend-and-axis-primary-and-secundar but i didn't manage to change the *last price* writing.

Comment: @Robert, to add a TA while supressing the "last price" text, just add the indicator into the next line after constructing the chart  , i.e:  `addVo()` to add the volume to the chart without "last price".

Comment: @hvollmeier Thanks for your reply, but when I run `chartSeries(hist.xts, type = 'bars', TA = NULL)` followed by `addVo()` on the next line, the chart text appears again.

Comment: Robert you are right. You have to use the experimental `chart_Series` and `add_vo()` functions (watch out for the underscore !) to generate a chart like this (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofh8rz41bna4du9/chart.png).